# ZFS: Removing files from snapshots?

Tags: zfs

Say I have a dataset with 100 snapshots and want to `rm -rf` all folders named "cache" in all snapshots.

I want to actually free up the space, not just hide it away in layers of snapshots, so making a clone and removing from that and then taking a new snapshot doesn't seem to do what I want.

Any semi-automatical way do that?
Some wrapping around zfs list -t snapshot, zfs clone, zfs promote, zfs snapshot?

*(cross-posted to [ZFS: Removing files from snapshots?](https://serverfault.com/questions/293009) as well)*

Comment: I see this was moved, so I guess http://serverfault.com/questions/293009 is now primary.